# Proper way handling nested ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, nested

I was wondering if there is any proper way to prevent ajax request from delivering random 404/500 Errors when calling many of them at the same time (synchronous or asynchronous)

e.g. a simple html table with some rows and columns to show a list of 500-800 people with some data

Way to go:

1. Getting ppl by selection (html form with organizational units) from the backend and write the resultlist in the first columns of the table
2. getting events of each person by his/her personId (result of the first request)
3. getting attributes of each person
4. getting roles for each person
5. getting calculated stuff from the backend for each person depending on their individual attributes,roles and events.

pseudocode:

```
function createTableData(){

  var selected;
  var personIds;

 //get personIds by selection and write them into table

 object.executeJSONRequest(...,
        {   _ts: new Date().getTime(),
            input: selected
        },function(data) {

                   // write result into table
                   // fill resourceIds with result param

        },..);

  getEvents(personIds);
  getAttribtues(personIds);
  getRoles(personIds);
  calculateStuff(personIds);

}


function getEvents(personIds){
   object.executeGetRequest('...',
        {   _ts: new Date().getTime(),
            ppl: personIds
        },function(data) {
                   //add result to table
        }
}

function getAttributes(personIds){...}  //and so on..
```

if i call all these methods in a row i sometimes get random errors sometimes while loading attributes, sometimes on loading roles, sometimes it all works fine.

if i call them nested in each ajax success block like

```
function createTableData(){

     object.executeJSONRequest(...
            {   _ts: new Date().getTime(),
                input: selected
            },function(data) {

                       getEvents(..);

                    });
 }

function getEvents(..){
  object.executeGETRequest(...
            {   _ts: new Date().getTime(),
                input: selected
            },function(data) {

                       getAttributes(..);

                    });
 }


function getAttributes(..){  ...,function(data){ getRole(..)});  and so on
```

it all works fine. If i try a solution with something like

```
 document.ajaxStart/Stop(function(){  //if table columns i expected are filled do next}
```

i have to check all neccessary table colums if they are already filled with data or not.

Is there any really proper solution i just dind't think about? 
(jQuery Version 1.2 /IE V7-8  ^^)

Answer (score 0):

*"If possible update jquery and ie versions"*

First of all why are you calling multiple server calls in a single process.

It's better if  you combine all the process into a single request and response cycle, do the required handling of data in java code.Don't go forth and back with request and response.

Any way you can use the jquery ajax which returns the status of the ajax call.

```
     $.post("url",function(result,status){{
            if(status == success){
    //continue....
    }else{
          alert("Sorry something went wrong");
         }
      }});
```

Like this check all the request weather it successfully finished.

I strongly recommend you consider combining all the ajax calls into a single request.

Comment: The problem is that i just get the data itemised. It's an existing application, the java backend just delivers single stuff so you can put them together as you wish. The only problem is if you need more taht one or two kind of things, depending on the result of each other it's becoming a mess -.- The jquery version and users with IE clients are defined as well. Would you check whether the success status is 200 or something like that?

Comment: jquery returns below listed values as the status
"success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or "parsererror"